# when can i detect the position of error in hamming code

Tags: error-correcting-codes, hamming-code

I have 4-bit data with the hamming code `0010011`.
the parity parameters are: `p1=0 , p2=0 , p3=0`
and the check codes are: `c1 = 0 , c2 = 1 , c3 = 0`
so I thought that I have an error in position 2 of my data but the solution says that I can not detect the position of the error.
my question is: when I can find the position of an error in hamming code?

Comment: okay , I think the solution was wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can never detect the positions of errors with certainty.

You can make *the assumption* that there is at most a single bit error. Under that assumption, if your code is not a valid code, you can find all different data where the hamming code differs from your code in only one bit position; if there is exactly *one* such data then you know where the error is (under your assumption).

You can make *the assumption* that there is at most a double bit error. Under that assumption, if your code is not a valid code, you can find all different data where the hamming code differs from your code in at most two bit positions; if there is exactly *one* such data then you know where the error or errors are (under your assumption).